# I can't connect to SQL Server - getting connection error

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection

I am somehow new with the coding. My error appears when I try to "transfer" the table from the SQL Server

[image: Pic:[username+other stuff]]

I have changed the name, I tried many things. Something weird is that when I go to Windows authentication, I still have the same files (I don't know if this is normal) and I also tried to do it without password but the error occurred faster.

[image: Pic:[the error]]

Comment: THis is for windows auth. check with this - Data Source=[Give urs];Initial Catalog=[Give urs];Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True

Comment: Thanks. i had tried this too but it didn't work

Comment: try adding ;Integrated Security=False;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;to the connection string

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried but this happened. Error at SQL connection (second line in the DataTable SlelectAll) Error: System.ArgumentException: 'Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 160.'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you choose the DB/conString to your Local DB DESKTOP-UB6UCB&, make the username and password same as its login
standart:
username = sa
password = as

Comment: U mean fro the pass sa right??? And pls explain DB/conString

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you have **TCP/IP** and **Named Pipes** enabled?
Open **SQL Server Configuration Manager** and enable both settings then restart the SQLSERVER service.

This can be necessary if you didn't choose allow Mixed Authentication when installing and configuring SQL Server.

The other suggestions about Integrated Security and Trusted_Connection above will also be helpful, but I believe that you have to enable TCP/IP and Named Pipes first.

Comment: I hope u answer. when i try to log into The Manager the server can't be found. Whats weird is it auto filled the name.

Comment: Can you post the error you see when opening SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Comment: error: No report server founds.

Comment: no need to answer i did the hole project again i don't know what the problem was but now it worked. weard